# Does urban Airship work on C2DM on backend on Android?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, backend, requirements, urbanairship.com

How Urban Airship does really work. Does it work same as C2DM on backend. what are the **requirement** for **Client** that want to use push notification from **Urban Airship.**

Comment: Urban Airship can actually use C2DM to deliver messages. Is that ["work same"](http://urbanairship.com/docs/android-client-push.html#a-tale-of-two-transports) enough for your client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urban Airship supports two push systems on Android: C2DM and Helium.

Specific documentation is available here:
https://docs.urbanairship.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=819543

The requirement for your client is to embed the Urban Airship library from our Resources page: http://urbanairship.com/resources/

You embed this library into your app, configure it, sign up on our service, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: if we want to use this library do we need any kind of server or not ? and how our application server will contact to it on server side